# Use static values in select2 then do ajax search

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-select2

I'm using `select2` 4.0.2 to provide a select box that does an AJAX lookup. But what I'd like to do is display the options in the `<option>` tags like a normal `<select>` until you start typing, and then go off to the server via AJAX to do more searching when your query string is non-empty.

Basically, the problem is that the AJAX query is a bit slow, but I can pre-load the first result on page load. I don't have to load it as `<option>`s, I could stuff them into a JSON array or something.

Comment: You cannot type in a normal select. Use `<input type='text' />` and add the `.select2()` on an Event.

Comment: I know you can't type in a normal select, I'm asking how to make select2 act like a normal select until you start typing.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing. In the select2 ajax options, first, in the data function, I stash the value and text from the options (because I don't have access to it in the transport function). Sorry this is in CoffeeScript:

```
data: (params) ->
  ret.q = params.term
  ret.page = params.page
  o = ({
    id: $(e).val(),
    display_name: $(e).text()
  } for e, index in this.children() when index > 0)
  ret.options = o
  return JSON.stringify(ret)
```

Then I declare a transport function that decides on whether to make an ajax call or use the local data:

```
transport: (params, success, failure) ->
   # Get query string
   params_data = $.parseJSON(params.data)
   q = params_data.q
   if !q || q.length < 3
     q_reg = new RegExp(q, "i")
     data =
       incomplete_results: false
       items: params_data.options.filter (element) ->
         q_reg.test(element.display_name)
     success(data)
   else
     $.ajax(params).done(success).fail(failure)
```